# Drupal on Elastic Beanstalk Redirects to Install.php on "eb deploy"

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am encountering what I believe to be permission issues when trying to deploy a Drupal application onto Elastic Beanstalk

I followed this tutorial to get Drupal up and running: http://comm-press.de/en/blog/drupal-climbs-aws-elastic-beanstalk

I am using a Postgres database and I am entering the correct credentials when filling out the forms on install.php, without error.

Any subsequent deploys after the initial deploy brings me back to install.php. After entering in my database information, I get this message, telling me Drupal is already installed (which it is).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKup7.png

Why does my site get redirected to install.php after 'eb deploy'? What permissions should I set my drupal folder such that settings.php and /sites/default/files is generated?

Comment: I'm guessing you are deploying standard Drupal everytime to the beanstalk instance?

Comment: What is standard Drupal? I have downloaded Drupal v7.37 from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal. I extracted the contents into my elastic beanstalk folder and ran a "eb deploy". Then, I run the installation and it finishes successfully. After, if I change any of the files in my drupal folder and deploy again, I get taken back to the installation.

After I run the installation, should "settings.php" and "/default/files" directories be created in my drupal folder on my local computer (they don't exist on my local computer)?

Comment: Sorry, Was supposed to add more information. When you installed drupal on elastic beanstalk, it creates a settings file with DB config ect. the next time you deployed the code to new instance, you are not actually deploying the this settings file but vanilla drupal code. What you will need to do is, run the installation locally and then do "eb deploy". You can also make use of Beanstalk "enviornment properties" to set different config values if you don't want to commit the settings to file.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. The instructions on the AWS page for creating a HA drupal website, seem to conveniently omit the steps for saving the site settings to the source. Fortunately the full instructions are on the AWS Labs github site. https://github.com/awslabs/eb-php-drupal#save-the-site-settings-to-source

Answer (score 0):

The install state is controlled by the DB-- if Drupal bootstraps with no DB information, you are routed to the code that asks you for it.

I was able to bypass this part by setting up a AWS RDS DB and connecting all instances to it.

--But, wait, there's more. Now that having all the instances reading from the same DB has squashed most of the concurrency problems between instances*. Go ahead, try and add a photo to your admin profile. I will wait. Yep, most of the time you'll get the wrong instance and the single image on one instance is not shown on all instances.
I am working on solving that problem with a start up & cron job script that loads updates to resources from the AWS S3 service.

```
Step A load code into S3
Step B set an accessible timestamp for $lastModified to now()


Step 1 wget/curl a timestamp of the last remote modification ($lastModified)
Step 2 compare the local last updated stamp ($lastUpdated) to remote last modified timestamp
Step 3 if ($lastModified == $lastUpdated) {die} else {update incremental changes && set $lastUpdated = $lastModified}
```

Watch that first incremental update, it's a doozy.

So... additionally I should mention that we are installing completely vanilla drupal when we instantiate an image, as part of the Docker file from drupal the drupal apache image the last thing the Docker file runs is a setup script.

Elastic Beanstalk sets Environment variables-- some of those variables are the amazon access key id and access secret key.

I curl an IP only available inside of Elastic Beanstalk curl -v 169.254.169.254

From that output in the setup script I can tell if I am local AWS EB or in AWS EB. That allows me to conditionally change certain configurations-- like connecting RDS or a local MySQL DB to Drupal.

The setup script uses aws cli to pull from S3 (sync) to add, replace, update everything in the webroot turning the instance into a setup Drupal installation as far as file level assets go.

sed and service reload is done a lot. Elasticache vs local Redis...

last we start the web server in the foreground && tail -f /dev/null so the container doesn't immediately close.

Drupal is just for static assets pages and a header/menu/footer wrapper for our web app (templates are served..., Twig/JS fills the template in with data). Authentication happens via API-- not even using 90% or so of the goodness in Drupal...

Incremental changes are pulled by comparing hash values and acting to run the update process if they are different.